# In Tensorflow, how to unravel the flattened indices obtained by tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I meet a problem: After I use the [tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#max_pool_with_argmax), I obtain the indices i.e. 
`argmax: A Tensor of type Targmax. 4-D. The flattened indices of the max values chosen for each output.`

How to unravel the flattened indices back to the coordinates list in Tensorflow?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today and I ended up with this solution:

```py
def unravel_argmax(argmax, shape):
    output_list = []
    output_list.append(argmax // (shape[2] * shape[3]))
    output_list.append(argmax % (shape[2] * shape[3]) // shape[3])
    return tf.pack(output_list)
```

Here is an [usage example](https://github.com/fabianbormann/Tensorflow-DeconvNet-Segmentation/blob/master/tests/UnpoolLayerTest.ipynb) in an ipython notebook (I use it to forward the pooling argmax positions to my unpooling method)

Comment: Cool. You implement Deconvnet with tensorflow.

Comment: Hi, could you comment a little on the maths behind it? How did you get to these expressions?