# tensorflow implementation for segnet

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow

Just curious, are there any Tensorflow implementation of [SegNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.00561). Looks like there are multiple Caffe implementation outside. Any information or insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one implementation on github: https://github.com/tkuanlun350/Tensorflow-SegNet

It is a little bit different because the indices unravel has not be achieved in tensorflow, the corresponding questions:
[In Tensorflow, how to unravel the flattened indices obtained by tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682201/in-tensorflow-how-to-unravel-the-flattened-indices-obtained-by-tf-nn-max-pool-w)
and
[In Tensorflow, how to assign values in Tensor according to the indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679697/in-tensorflow-how-to-assign-values-in-tensor-according-to-the-indices)